# Import and activate connection with nmcli as normal user

Tags: virtualbox, vpn, networkmanager

When trying to import the settings for a VPN into network manager using

`nmcli connection import type openvpn file settings.ovpn`

nmcli throws an error saying 'insufficient privileges'.
I am using this on a very basic headless Debian/Stretch system.

When using the same command with the same version of network-manager (1.6.2) and the same `settings.ovpn` file in another Debian system (Sid, with cinnamon GUI), everything works just fine.
Both users are part of the same groups, except some groups related to virtualbox

`dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev scanner bluetooth vboxsf webdev nm-openvpn`

I have tried defining a polkit definition as explained here, but to no avail: https://jeffhoogland.blogspot.it/2012/05/howto-give-network-manager-sufficient.html

Could running the system as a virtualbox guest system have something to do with the error?
What am I missing?

**Edit:**
Activating the connection after setting the permissions via

`nmcli connection modify ConnectionID connection.permissions:user`

works just fine, so this is probably a problem with permissions. But still: How can I make it possible to import vpn connections as a normal user?